# WebRequest slower in multiply tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, webrequest

When I work on the WebRequest inside tasks under Mono, I found that it's very slow to get response from server. But it very fast if sending request out Task. I did some research but there is no solution for it. The code works well on Windows and .NET Core on Linux. So I guess it maybe a problem on Mono. Hope someone can help me out of it.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(async _ =>
        {
            var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            await ValidateUrlAsync("https://www.bing.com");

            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            //request.Abort();
        }).ToArray();

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        // Single request
        {
            var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            ValidateUrlAsync("https://www.bing.com").ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static async Task<bool> ValidateUrlAsync(string url)
    {
        using(var response = (HttpWebResponse)await WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponseAsync())
            return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
```

The Mono version: 5.16.0.179.
Ubuntu: 16.04.2 LTS.

Comment: I think the issue is something else because I just switched the execution sequence like first without `Task` and then with the `Task`. Now it takes almost the same time.

Comment: Are you able to use `HttpClient` instead?

Comment: @Keyur Ramoliya I tried it again based on your description. At first time, it worked like your description, it took almost the same time, however I ran it a few times, it became very slow, even took approximately 5s to finish the task.

Comment: @mjwills Unfortunately, I was unable to use HttpClient instead, because it's from the a libaray.

Comment: try to do the same but with http instead of https, maybe the bottleneck is in the TLS negotiation

Comment: (also if I were you I would also try with Ubuntu 18.04 instead of 16.04)

Comment: @knocte I tried to run the application with Ubuntu 18.04, but get the same behavior with on Ubuntu 16.04.